# How to get the last value with the maximum timestamp in ingestion spec in apache druid?

Tags: druid, data-ingestion

I read druid docs about aggregator at https://druid.apache.org/docs/latest/querying/aggregations.html

I wanna use like this

```
{
  "type" : "longLast",
  "name" : <output_name>,
  "fieldName" : <metric_name>,
}
```

**But There is specified at this docs, First/Last aggregator cannot be used in ingestion spec.**

I don't know how to get the last value(metric spec) at ingestion time.

Is there a solution to address this problem?

Answer (score 1):

stringFirst/stringLast aggregators work at ingestion from the 0.20.0 Druid version.